# Toggle show hide others using child or compound, not parent?

Tags: jquery, toggle, children

How to get toggle show hide from click of children or compound, not the click on parent?

I want to toggle Image A when click on Thumbnail A, not from the click of entire `div`.
Thanks.

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <dl>
    <dt>Thumbnail A</dt>
    <dd>Name A</dd>
    <dd>Price A</dd>
  </dl>

  <ul class="details">
    <li>Image A</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div').click(function() {
    var then = $(".details", this)
    $(then).toggle();
    $(".details:visible").not(then).hide();
  });
});
```

The answers given from the like of Maverick, David Thomas, j08691 and Tushar Gupta are pretty valid one using `parent.siblings`, but originally I've tried using compound like this:

```
$('div dl dt').click(function(){
```

But it wont work. I reckoned it has something to do with the var.

But please bear in mind I really need that, the toggle close when other toggle open and close itself when click on 'Thumbnail A' and so on, whic is `dt`, not `div`.

The compound alone work fine as it is but its now what I want to achieve. Here goes the original one.

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/pandaktuai/v46zA/

And here with the mess up variable that achieve what I need but, the click can only select the most outer element, which is parent, (`div`).

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/pandaktuai/Jeb86/

I hope I've shown my minimal understanding of this problem and much thanks if you all can lend me a hand.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply modefy your js to this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('dt').click(function(){

 var then = $(this).parent().siblings(".details");
 $(then).toggle();
 $(".details:visible").not(then).hide();
});

});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Jeb86/1/

Comment: Hey Maverick,thanks.
I cant thanks enough, can I just rate up all your guys answers.
Again,thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally suggest:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // selecting the 'dt' element(s),
    // using the 'click()' method to handle the 'click' events:
    $('dt').click(function(){
        // moving up through the ancestors to find the first ancestor 'div'
        // finding the '.details' element(s) within that 'div' ancestor
        // toggling its visibility (hiding if it's visible, showing if it's hidden):
        $(this).closest('div').find('.details').toggle();
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Jeb86/3/).

If, as suggested (in comments, below) [by j08691](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877927/toggle-show-hide-others-using-child-not-parent#comment27861145_18878069), it's required that clicking showing *one* `.details` element should hide the others (as well as toggling the visibility of the relevant `.details` element):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('dt').click(function(){
        var target = $(this).closest('div').find('.details').toggle();
        $('.details').not(target).hide();
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Jeb86/5/).

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: This doesn't work as clicking Thumbnail A followed by Thumbnail B shows both.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't see that requirement in the question.

Comment: The OP didn't explain it but if you look at his code, specifically the `then` variable assignment plus `$(".details:visible").not(then).hide();` it's pretty clear he wants to hide the thumbnails not clicked on.

Comment: Tahnks David Thomas, j08691, Maverick and Tushar Gupta. It's all valid, so what i've been missing is parent.siblings right?
I cant thanks enough, can I just rate up all your guys answers.
Again,thanks.

Comment: I figured that I need 15 points to rate all your guys answers,bum.
But,out of technically,this toggle effect is kinda like itune folder,google image so is it a problem if I apply it to my web?
Yeahh noob ,sorry, cause I learn somewhere google sued by others company that apply it to their website earlier, ending with google acquired that company.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('dt').click(function () {
        var then = $(this).parent().siblings(".details");
        $(this).parent().next().toggle();
        $(".details:visible").not(then).hide();
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Jeb86/2/)**

Comment: j08691,thanks. Yes I copy paste from my above reply,but really,thanks
I cant thanks enough, can I just rate up all your guys answers.
Again,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jeb86/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div').find('dl dt').click(function (e) {
        var then = $(this).closest('div').find(".details");
        $(then).toggle();
        $(".details:visible").not(then).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Tushar Gupta,thanks. Yes I copy paste from my above reply again,but really,thanks
I cant thanks enough, can I just rate up all your guys answers.
Again,thanks.